# Getting this error message while running scrapy spider connected to mysql database: ERROR: Error processing {'availability':

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, mysql-python

I am building a scrapy spider that is connected to a mysql database. It's going to a website with a list of books and returning info about the books (price, title, availability, etc). When I run the spider without connecting it to the database, having the results returned into a json or csv file, it works great. But when connecting it to the database, it gives me this error, and then when i check the created database, its empty.

Error message:

```
'num_reviews': 0,
 'price_excl_tax': 17.03,
 'price_incl_tax': 17.03,
 'product_type': 'books',
 'stars': 3,
 'tax': 0.0,
 'title': 'Balloon Animals',
 'upc': '9b65f676984c9f0c',
 'url': 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/balloon-animals_665/index.html'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\14694\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\14694\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 304, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\14694\Desktop\Repositories\LearningScrapy\FirstSpider\bookscraper\bookscraper\pipelines.py", line 107, in process_item
    self.cur.execute(""" insert into books (
  File "C:\Users\14694\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 598, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "C:\Users\14694\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 127, in __call__
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
2023-05-04 11:55:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'availability': 14,
 'category': 'food and drink',
```

Here is the relevant code from my item pipelines file.

```
import mysql.connector

class SaveToMySQLPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = 'Pharoah1017$', #add your password here if you have one set 
            database = 'books'
        )

        ## Create cursor, used to execute commands
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        ## Create books table if none exists
        self.cur.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(
            id int NOT NULL auto_increment, 
            url VARCHAR(255),
            title text,
            upc VARCHAR(255),
            product_type VARCHAR(255),
            price_excl_tax DECIMAL,
            price_incl_tax DECIMAL,
            tax DECIMAL,
            price DECIMAL,
            availability INTEGER,
            num_reviews INTEGER,
            stars INTEGER,
            category VARCHAR(255),
            description text,
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
        """)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        ## Define insert statement
        self.cur.execute(""" insert into books (
            url, 
            title, 
            upc, 
            product_type, 
            price_excl_tax,
            price_incl_tax,
            tax,
            price,
            availability,
            num_reviews,
            stars,
            category,
            description
            ) values (
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s,
                %s
                )""", (
            item["url"],
            item["title"],
            item["upc"],
            item["product_type"],
            item["price_excl_tax"],
            item["price_incl_tax"],
            item["tax"],
            item["price"],
            item["availability"],
            item["num_reviews"],
            item["stars"],
            item["category"],
            str(item["description"][0])
        ))

        # ## Execute insert of data into database
        self.conn.commit()
        return item

    
    def close_spider(self, spider):

        ## Close cursor & connection to database 
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close(

)
```

I am confused as to how to proceed. When running the spider, I can see that its returning all the other info without a problem, as I can see the results coming up in the terminal. It just gives me this error on each book when it gets to the 'availability' information. I have tried resetting my VE and running it again, but that didn't change anything.

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm new to using `mysql` in this way and could use some help.

Comment: it tells you in the traceback what the problem is.  it is not receiving enough parameters for the sql statement.